# is it possible to add a class dynamically with css

Tags: html, css

I know that doing such thing with Javascript is easy but is there any way to add some class dynamically with CSS ? for example can I add `.bg-color` class when mouse hover ? what can I do in hover section

```
<div class="mydiv">
  <p> This is the text </p>
</div>
<style>
.mydiv { width:100% ; height: 20vh; text-align:center}
.bg-color { background-color:red;}
.mydiv:hover{
}
</style>
```

Comment: No actually you cannot do that in css

Comment: You can add that specific styling with :hover. I do not think anything else is possible with only css.

Comment: @MajiD oh , ok , so  I will go with js

Comment: @TusharShahi I think the closest way is your way

Comment: Basically CSS is used for styling purposes, and I don't think we can add any dynamic class. Instead we can use JS. I know how to implement this is reactJS, If that helps then let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you could try this, and it is always better to define a class and use it in css instead of using the style tag.

```css
body {
  background-color: #000000;
}

.hvr {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 80px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #087ee1, #05e8ba 50%, white 50%);
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  background-size: 200% 100%;
  background-position: 100%;
  transition: background-position 275ms ease;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.hvr:hover {
  background-position: 0 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <a class="hvr" href="#">TEST-1</a>
</body>
```

Comment: "it is always better to define a class and use it in css instead of using the style tag" - is this true?

Comment: Well in most cases,  suppose you define a footer class and apply all the style properties in CSS. Then, you can easily use that class in multiple pages, elements or tags whereas, if u are using the style tag u have to write those lines for each and every element which essentially becomes cumbersome when u have multiple html files.

Comment: Yes, it was the 'always' that I feel isn't quite true, many times it is of course more maintainable not to have inline.